# Weird undefined references on template linkedlist class

Tags: c++, list, templates

Together.cpp: Code: http://pastebin.com/yMFMKe1K Output + Compilation: 
[image: Output + Compilation] But, when split into the LinkedList class. CPP: http://pastebin.com/3hLYb18X H: http://pastebin.com/ibEZQ0ut main: http://pastebin.com/AmFf65KC
It decides to error![image: Error 1] Even worse, when uncommenting the iterate function, it gives me an even scarier error! [image: Error 2]
I'm very sorry for the inconvenience caused by the bad formatting of this post. Please can I have some help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates must be fully defined in the header file (i.e, no .cpp). Just cut & paste your implementation from your .cpp to the bottom of your header.

Comment: Further information on this topic: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)